# Compare two pandas dataframes for equality, under several conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, compare, equality

What's the Python pandas equivalent of the [`compare`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compare/compare.pdf) package in R which contains a function of the same name, that compares two datasets under several aspects:

- You can pass different arguments to the `compare()` function to specify which differences between df1 and df2 should be accepted.
- If two datasets are equal, but the one is longer because of covering a larger time period, so you can set `short=TRUE`.

The whole list of possible arguments (in R) is:

```
compare(model, comparison,
        equal = TRUE,
        coerce = allowAll,
        shorten = allowAll,
        ignoreOrder = allowAll,
        ignoreNameCase = allowAll,
        ignoreNames = allowAll,
        ignoreAttrs = allowAll,
        round = FALSE,
        ignoreCase = allowAll,
        trim = allowAll,
        dropLevels = allowAll,
        ignoreLevelOrder = allowAll,
        ignoreDimOrder = allowAll,
        ignoreColOrder = allowAll,
        ignoreComponentOrder = allowAll,
        colsOnly = !allowAll,
        allowAll = FALSE)
```

Does Python have a similar package, that can handle different cases of difference and equality between two datasets. I haven't found an equivalent to R's `compare` function yet.

The closest I found yet to `compare` is `pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, expected, check_names=False)` function, which is not as broad as compare().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after months of working with Python I can present the answer to own question.

For comparing **two arrays** use functions from **numpy** package.

```
numpy.array_equal(array1,array2)  # test if the same shape and values
numpy.array_equiv(array1,array2)  # test if shape consistent and all elements equal
numpy.allclose(array1,array2) # test if same shape, elements have close values
```

Documentation of these functions can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/).

---

That's now what I needed, but maybe it can be hepful for somebody: 
for comparing **two sequences of text** use **difflib** package, which helps to compare HTML, .txt files etc. Documentation can be read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html).